# Compiling and Routing files under bower_component folder in Nanoc

Tags: ruby, nanoc

I want to take and put some of the files under `bower_components` folder. In my web site, `bower_components` folder tree is as follows:

```
├── bower_components
│   └── angular
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── angular-csp.css
│       ├── angular.js
│       ├── angular.min.js
│       ├── angular.min.js.gzip
│       ├── angular.min.js.map
│       └── bower.json
```

I just want to copy the `angular.min.js` file to the `output/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js` folder.

For this purpose, I modified the Rules file as below:

```
compile "/bower_components/*.min.js" do
  #item.identifier.chop + '.' + item[:extension]
end

route "/bower_components/*.min.js" do
  item.identifier.chop + '.' + item[:extension]
end
```

When I compile my website, I have the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Found 4 content files for content/bower_components/angular/angular; expected 0 or 1

Compilation stack:

  (empty)

Stack trace:

  0. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/data_sources/filesystem.rb:164:in `block in all_split_files_in'
  1. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/data_sources/filesystem.rb:154:in `each_pair'
  2. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/data_sources/filesystem.rb:154:in `all_split_files_in'
  3. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/data_sources/filesystem.rb:78:in `load_objects'
  4. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/data_sources/filesystem.rb:37:in `items'
  5. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/base/source_data/site.rb:325:in `block in load_items'
  6. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/base/source_data/site.rb:324:in `each'
  7. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/base/source_data/site.rb:324:in `load_items'
  8. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/base/source_data/site.rb:243:in `load'
  9. /Users/neva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/nanoc-3.6.7/lib/nanoc/base/source_data/site.rb:127:in `layouts'
  ... 27 more lines omitted. See full crash log for details.
```

What shall be the problem?

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way it maps input filenames onto output paths, Nanoc requires the base name (i.e., the filename less extension) of each file under `content` to be unique. From Nanoc's perspective you are giving it four files that share the base name `angular` and thus cannot have unique output paths, so it gives you this error.

Since what you really want is to have Nanoc copy over this portion of your site verbatim, you ought to set up a static data source from which to load it. Then Nanoc will simply copy the files over as-is without attempting to process or rename them. The ["Troubleshooting"](http://nanoc.ws/docs/troubleshooting/) page on the Nanoc website has instructions on how to do this; see "Solution #2" under ["Error: “Found 3 content files for X; expected 0 or 1”](http://nanoc.ws/docs/troubleshooting/#error-found-3-content-files-for-x-expected-0-or-1).

Comment: I usually set up my whole bower directory as a static data source, since this is almost exclusively where I run into the "N content files for X" error.